# how to use Angular UI grid downloadpdf function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[image]

first paremeter is the filename and second is docDefinition(which value i will pass in second parameter) still confuse?

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is an object that have all the options of "pdfmake".

> The most fundamental concept to be mastered is the
>   document-definition-object which can be as simple as:
>
> `var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed withpdfMake' };`
>
> or become pretty complex (having multi-level tables,
>   images, lists, paragraphs, margins, styles etc...).

You can check the documentation on Github https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake and do it more complex.

But if you use the function **pdfExport**, this one create the object with the data grid and **it is more easy**, Try this:

```
$scope.gridApi.exporter.pdfExport( uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL );
```

And they have more options that you can change in gridOptions:

```
exporterPdfDefaultStyle:{ fontSize: 11 },
exporterPdfFilename: 'filename.pdf',
exporterPdfTableHeaderStyle: { bold: true, fontSize: 12, color: 'black' },
exporterPdfTableStyle : { margin: [0, 5, 0, 15] },
exporterPdfHeader : null,
exporterPdfFooter : null,
gridOptions.exporterPdfOrientation : 'landscape',
```

etc...